# "Тепло и звукоизоляция" или "тепло- и звукоизоляция"

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно: **тепло и звукоизоляция** или **тепло- и звукоизоляция**?

Answer (score 6):

Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют "висячим", например:

*шарико- и роликоподшипники; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы; как водо-, так и газоснабжение; до- или послеперестроечные процессы; обер- и унтер-офицеры*.
[**Дефис, сложные слова, § 112**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59)

*Тепло/изоляция и звуко/изоляция* — общим конечным элементом сложных слов является "изоляция", поэтому правильно будет написать так:
***тепло- и звукоизоляция*** (или ***теплозвукоизоляция***).